# How to import 3D models to iOS game

Tags: ios, opengl-es, 3d, blender, 3dsmax

am working on iOS 3D game and am new in this field, am not looking for a code, just some advice on how can I get a model designed on 3D max, Blender or Sketchup loaded on my iOS project. For example, in what kind of format do I need to export the model, so I can use it on openGL ES; or what kind of open source library (3D game engine) that might be used to import the model to my project.

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.com/index.php/documentation/platform-specifics/ios/23-configuring-cmake-for-ios)

OR

[Cocos3D](http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/)

Cocos3D have a pluggable loading framework for 3D models exported from familiar 3D editors such as Blender, 3ds Max or Cheetah3D, or through industry standard 3D object files such as Collada or PowerVR POD, or even from your own customized object file formats.

There are many options, you just have to search a bit.

Comment: I spent about 45 minutes trying to get `OSG` to build for XCode, and finally just bailed after a lot of errors and "me too"s on SO.  Hopefully, there's an easier solution.  `Cocos3d` is a fine product, but more than I care to deal with, at the moment.  I'm really just trying to import .3ds files into something I can pass to my `EAGLView`!